# load page with tinymce (AJAX)

Tags: ajax, tinymce, wysiwyg

Im not having problem with loading the page using jQuery but when I load the page with textarea that should have tinymce dont show.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'textarea.php',
data: {data: info},
async: false,
beforeSend: function() {
},
complete: function() {
},        
cache: false,
success:  function(result) {
  $('#form-area').html(result);
}
error: function(error) {
alert("Some problems have occured. Please try again later: " + error);
}
```

});

Comment: can we get some of your code? what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should call the `tinymce.init` function right after the html code from the ajax request has been insered into the dom. You may alternatively call

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
```

You need to keep in mind that you should shut down the tinymce editor instance in case you want to reload the editor instance using ajax. Use in this case

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

Comment: mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",  //can editor_id can be change to class_name??

Comment: the editor will take the id of the underlying html element (usually a textarea), you can change that id accordingly

Answer (score 0):

When you switch pages with ajax TinyMCE seems to break.To solve this I added the following code to remove any existing TinyMCE instances before initializing it again

```
  if(window.tinymce){
    $(window.tinymce.editors).each(function(idx, p) {
    window.tinymce.remove(idx);
    });
  }

  tinyMCE.init({
        selector: "#risksummary",
        menubar: false,
        plugins : "table",
        toolbar: "table"
    });
```